# Can somebody explain this mediaelement and audio tags

Tags: media, audio

I'm using this built in audio tag. It works for mp3 but with wma I just get this "Download file" link.

I read this: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wmv-videos-are-not-playing

but setting type="audio/vma" does not fix the problem.

This is the link to some page that has the same problem as me:
http://shastacosta.com/dwight/wp36-wma

Comment: Looks like it's working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WMA isn't a standard format. It will only play natively in IE9 and up, and will only play in other browsers if they have Silverlight installed.

Comment: oh.. so only use mp3 than.. :)